# Android: Keyboard is flickering when the EditText input type is number

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a layout for list items. Inside that layout list item, I have an Edit Text with input type as number.

My issue is when i click on the edit text the keyboard is flickering with normal alpha numerical key board and number key.

I am not getting any idea why it is happens.

**Layout.xml**

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/total"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/bg_white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/view_cart_count_min_width"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_normal"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_normal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.manoramaonline.entedeal.MyCartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
```

when I change the softInputMode to adJustPan  the keyboard flickirinf is stop, but the screen not resizing. So the keyboard is comes over the layout.

When android:windowSoftInputMode is adjust resize with edit text input type number that time the keyboard is flickering

I there any solution that reduce the screen size when the soft keyboard is open.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Binil Surendran Did you find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  I had an Edit Text inside of an list adapter.  In the xml for the ExitText, I had 
android:inputType="numberDecimal".

In the manifest file, I had the following line for the activity:
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
When I would select an edit box, it only displayed the numeric keypad (and stopped all of that thrashing).

I picked this up from question 28674967.

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

use this

Comment: not working and my button which using alignParentButtom doesn't show at the top of the keyboard softInputMode

Comment: I am facing similar issue, but only on Honor Device. Any solution for this ?